# A link of a table cell background opens in a new tab?

Tags: html, hyperlink, html-table, target

My website has a one row html table, which each sell is a link to Google translate URL. Though I've not used any "target" parameter, the translated pages are opening as a new tab in my browser. Why it happens and how can I make them open in the same main page where the links are executing from? Isn't this a default?

```
<td align="center" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="window.open('http://www.example.com/en/#googtrans(en|en)'); Link();">English</td>
```

I just want that my URL will be changed from `www.example.com/en`

Into `http://www.example.com/en/#googtrans(en|en)` at the same window.

I've also a second link that activated by onClick and changing iframe area at the same page in one click, but I don't think this is the cause.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
window.location.assign("http://www.example.com/en/#googtrans(en|en)"
```

Comment: Thanks, the link is working, but the part Link();" won't execute. This part is calling other page to load into and iframe at the same page. I understand that I'm moving from this page out, but is there any solution, like open the iframe in targeted link page for example?

Comment: As you said, the Link() cannot be executed. I do not know the configuration of your files. But you can simply execute the function in the page `http://www.example.com/en/#googtrans(en|en)` onload. It should work.